# Progress Dialog never ends in case of slow or no internet connectivity

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

My app gets data from server and saves to sqlite using asyntask, but if there is slow or no internet connectivity the progress dialog never finishes and keeps searching for the internet.My app also runs the service for uploading the records to the server so i don't want to use another timer in the code. Please suggest me any solution.

```
 public class DoctorsCallPlannigOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void,  String> {

ProgressDialog pd;
Context cxt;
public static List<String> listplannum;
public static List<String> listrefnum;
public static List<String> listcreateddate;
public static List<String> listdrcode;
public static List<String> listplandate;
public static List<String> listffmgr;
public static List<String> listffcode;
public static List<String> listmon;
public static List<String> listterrcode;
public static List<String> listmorn_even;

public static String tmp,TerrCode;

// String Response = "{\"Successful\":true}";

public DoctorsCallPlannigOperation(Context context,String terrcode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    cxt = context;
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setTitle("Please wait");
    pd.setMessage("Loading...");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    cxt= context;
    TerrCode=terrcode;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    RestAPI restAPI = new RestAPI();
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

    try {

        jsonObj = restAPI.getDocCallsPlanning(TerrCode);        
        tmp = jsonObj.toString();


        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(tmp);
        JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("Value");

        listplannum = new ArrayList<String>();
        listrefnum = new ArrayList<String>();
        listcreateddate = new ArrayList<String>();
        listdrcode = new ArrayList<String>();
        listplandate = new ArrayList<String>();
        listffmgr = new ArrayList<String>();
        listffcode = new ArrayList<String>();
        listmon = new ArrayList<String>();
        listterrcode = new ArrayList<String>();
        listmorn_even = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            listplannum.add(jo.getString("PLAN_NO"));
            listrefnum.add(jo.getString("REF_NO"));
            listcreateddate.add(jo.getString("CREATED_DATE"));
            listdrcode.add(jo.getString("DR_CODE"));
            listplandate.add(jo.getString("PLAN_DATE"));
            listffmgr.add(jo.getString("FF_MGR"));
            listffcode.add(jo.getString("FF_CODE"));
            listmon.add(jo.getString("MON"));
            listterrcode.add(jo.getString("TERR_CODE"));
            listmorn_even.add(jo.getString("MORN_EVEN"));


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("AsyncGetSpecialities", e.getMessage());

    }

    return tmp;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    pd.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This need to be in onPreExecute:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
pd.setTitle("Please wait");
pd.setMessage("Loading...");
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.show();
```

And this need to be in onPostExecute:

```
if(pd != null)
pd.dismiss();
```